# Style ancestor element of form input:focus (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, focus, background, selector

I have a form with a DIV, 3 INPUTS, each INPUT sits within a LABEL element. I would like to change the background image of the DIV element when focusing on each INPUT.

I can't move back up the DOM to fix this with CSS, so could someone suggest a few lines of jQuery please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div input').focus(function(){
    $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').addClass('specialCSSclass');
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').removeClass('specialCSSclass');
});
```

You would need to create a class in your CSS and then replace "specialCSSclass" with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
}).blur(function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery closest is also an option.

```
closest( selector )
    .closest( selector )
    .closest( selector, [ context ] )
closest( selectors, [ context ] )
    .closest( selectors, [ context ] )
```

Per the description.. Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/